# I can reach my machine vis SSH but not Remote Desktop within my network

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, vnc

I've set up 22.04 desktop on a wyse thin client to eventually act as an always available Jellyfin server. I've set up remote desktop access in sharing (including VNC) and have successfully used TightVNC view to get to the Ubuntu desktop from my Win10 machine. I've not successfully figured out logging in via rdp and Windows on RDP client.

I should note, my instance of Ubuntu on the thin client starts when powered on (it's not asking me to log into my account to access the desktop). I did set the bios to restart the machine in the even that it lost power but I am unclear what I did that no longer has ubuntu asking me to log into the desktop but that's not the core of question. I have the thin client on my network and I am able to SSH into the machine but I am unable to get remote desktop access and cannot figure out why. I have the Gnome Allow Locked Desktop extension installed, which helped me get in internally gain remote desktop access, but I wouldn't think would play a part when I'm not being asked to unlock my desktop.

I'm unsure what to do to figure out what is happening, or not running, that is preventing me remote desktop access. What commands might I run to make sure the remote desktop server is running? How to unravel why I cannot log in?

Is it possible that the ubuntu instance starting automatically is a user and with that user logged in I am not allowed access?

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to the RDP via ubuntu client, are you using
rdp://xxx.x.x.xxx or ms-rd://xxx.xxx.x.xxx?

for me the first one works.

also the best app i have used for rdp is 'connections'.
Which is available via flathub.